# NPM Dependency Help needed

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-package

I have this error from an npm audit

```
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@2.1.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=2.1.4
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          node_modules/react-scripts
```

I ran npm ls svgr (not sure if that was helpful)
And got this:

```
└─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
  ├─┬ @svgr/webpack@5.5.0
  │ └─┬ @svgr/plugin-svgo@5.5.0
  │   └── svgo@1.3.2
  └─┬ css-minimizer-webpack-plugin@3.4.1
    └─┬ cssnano@5.1.15
      └─┬ cssnano-preset-default@5.2.14
        └─┬ postcss-svgo@5.1.0
          └── svgo@2.8.0
```

I am not sure what to do to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The following article by Dan Abramov provides a great explanation of why `npm audit` vulnerabilities related to `react-scripts` are not real security issues in most cases.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11174

**tl;dr;**

1. Move your `react-scripts` dependency to `devDependencies`
2. Run `npm audit --production` instead of `npm audit`